# Matching the comments of comment out lines

Tags: regex, regex-negation, regex-lookarounds

I'd like to match the comments of the comment out lines, when searching in my editor (equivalent of multiline-mode, or so I believe?).

The regex `(?<!^)%.+?$` matches the comment of the commented out first line of the following code correctly (Everything after a `%` is commented out),

```
 % foo = bar() % First comment

      % baz = qui() % Second commment
```

but I can't figure out how to also match the second line, assuming it's indented by an unknown number of spaces or tabs.

I tried and failed doing this: `((?<!^)%.+?$|(?<!^\s)%.+?$)`

(My previous regex put in a "`or`-bracket", duplicated and extended to allow for an unknown number of spaces; breaks the regex, as the `+`and `*` operators apparently arent allowed in look`(`ahead`|`behind`)`s).

Comment: First what's a comment ? Everything between `%` (so there are two `%` to make a comment) or everything after `%` (so there is only one `%` per comment) ?

Comment: Everyting after er `%`is a comment.

This is two lines of code, which both is commented out. In addition, both of them also have a comment after the assignments to `foo` and `baz`.

Thank you for asking for clarification of the question.

Comment: [This might be a solution](http://regex101.com/r/dH9gA4) if you can use captured groups.

Comment: Yes, but it's a bit messy. The reason I need to match the comments of the commented out lines only, is that I want to reformat like [this](http://pastebin.com/wWq7Kwfa). 

It can be done, but I admit I was hoping for a more elegant method (which might be stupid, considering the messy nature of regexes).

Comment: Note that arbitrary repetition (`+` or `*`) is allowed in lookaheads, just not in lookbehinds (unless your editor uses .NET's regex flavor). On a different note, why do you begin your pattern with `(?<!%)`? This way it would match all comment lines, unless the very first character in the line is the `%` (if there is a space or any character before it, the comment would be matched).

Comment: Nice to know about arbitrary repition operators in lookaheads.
But I believe I begin my pattern with `(?<!^)`, not `(?<!%)`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`^\s*%[^%\n]*%(.*?)$` should do the job.

Explanation:

```
^        # Start of a line
\s*      # 0 or more white spaces
%        # Just a regular % sign
[^%\n]*  # Matches 0 or more times anything that is not a % or a new line (\n)
%        # Just a regular % sign
(.*?)    # Captures everything after the second % (ungreedy)
$        # End of a line (because the previous in ungreedy it will not match items on the new line
```

This shows look arounds are not always the best approach for certain problems.

I tested it on the following data in Notepad++

```
% foo = bar() % First comment
% test 
      % baz = qui() % Second commment
someFunction()
```

Replacing it with the first captured group results in: (this shows that only the correct parts are captured)

```
 First comment
% test 
 Second commment
someFunction()
```

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer – the detailed explanation is nice.

I generally think it's hard to know when to use "lookers"; this have been educating for me :)